# Terminated due to timeout Mapping phone numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, hash-map

I have a code based on the following problem "Mapping phone numbers to names", the problem is that when they are going to process large data(+100.000) the program ends by timeout. my code and problem is [this](https://gist.github.com/heanfig/60b5dcc9e9fdec214aae6b6c563b7430), how can I optimize my code to consume less time?

my code

```js
function processData(input) {
  var r=input.split(/\n/),o=Number(r[0]),c=r.length-1,x=[];
  r.splice(0,o+1);
  r.forEach((l)=>{
      var rx=new RegExp(l+"\\s(\\d+)"),o=input.match(rx);
      console.log(o==null?"Not found":l+"="+o[1]);
  });
}
```

Example Input

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

Example Output

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

The program generates timeout in the following case

BIG Example [Input and output](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B21QmlA3rW3tazdlTnZJTUp6cjg?usp=sharing) 
Thanks

Comment: Pay heed to the motto of the day: `Dictionaries and Maps`.

Comment: include an example of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Naming

Single character name is a bad practice. Use the descriptive names for variables.

```
r => rows
o => noOfRecords
c => noOfRows
x => ...
```

They are not searchable and can be easily confused with numbers. For example, `l` and `1`, `0` and `o`/`O`.

### Dead/Unused Code

Variables `c` and `x` are not used and thus can be removed.

### Overriding Variables

`<opinion-based>`Variable `o` is used to get the first line in the file and then inside `forEach` it is again used to store the match result. This will work fine, but will also confuse other users(or you after few months). The variables should be used for single-purpose.`</opinion-based>`

### Slice down input data

Inside `forEach`, `input` data is used to search for the name. `input` here is complete data with the number of records on the first line, name-numbers and then names.
This data can be sliced down to keep only name-number. This will reduce the data to work on and will improve the performance.

```
var rows = input.split(/\n/);
var nameAndNumbers = rows.slice(1, numberOfRows + 1);
```

and use `nameAndNumbers` to search name from.

---

As [greybeard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/93149/greybeard) mentioned in [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166642/terminated-due-to-timeout-mapping-phone-numbers#comment317210_166642), you should use [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)/[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the name and number.

```
function processData(input) {
    var rows = input.split(/\n/);
    var numberOfRows = Number(rows[0]);

    var nameAndNumbers = rows.slice(1, numberOfRows + 1);
    var names = rows.slice(numberOfRows + 1);

    var phoneBook = {};
    nameAndNumbers.forEach(function(number) {
        var data = number.split(' ');
        phoneBook[data[0]] = data[1];
    });

    return names.map(name => phoneBook[name] ? name + '=' + phoneBook[name] : 'Not Found').join('\n');
}
```